# tsconfig exclude compilation of certain folders in .NET Core project

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am tearing my hair out trying to get my .NET Core Angular 2 app to ignore files when building.  Here is my systemjs.config.js :

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': '../lib/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

        // angular bundles
      'ng2-translate': 'npm:ng2-translate/bundles/ng2-translate.umd.js',
      'ng2-sharebuttons': 'npm:ng2-sharebuttons',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
    },
      // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        '/app': {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'ng2-translate': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'ng2-sharebuttons': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

After adding ng2-sharebuttons, which contains a number of .d.ts files, whenever I try to build the solution I get build errors relating to certain .d.ts files.  Although there are many .d.ts files in the @angular folder but they do not cause any errors.  I have tried several other external libraries though and they all have the same issue for me.

Here is my tsconfig :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/lib"
  ]
}
```

I have tried excluding the folders from the solution in Visual Studio and hiding the folders, but then the libraries cannot be found at all. Can anybody advise? Do I need to add typings for any external libraries?

Comment: What build tool are you using? That is, are you building directly with `tsc` or are you using something like `gulp` to call it?

Comment: I am using the Build Solution option in the Build menu in Visual Studio

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015